# Clicking on the cross to remove an option in multi-select box of Angular-UI-Select redirects to app home

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have an AngularJS app with multiple routes. On one of the pages, I'm using Angular-UI-Select.

Clicking on the cross button to remove an option in the multi-select box of Angular-UI-Select redirects to the home of the app, instead of removing the option.

I think the reason for this issue could be that the URL already has a `#` at the app home, and the cross button is also linking to `#` causing the browser to redirect to the home.

I have looked at the [demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2/preview), which work fine but doesn't have an existing `#` in the URL. Is there any workaround to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This should be already fixed with this [commit](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/commit/64dc9af1be074982859587b24470f1f450152e18)